# Proof for triangle inequality generalized to integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose $\vec h : [a, b] \to R^n$ is continuous. Then show that;

$$\bigg|\bigg| \int_a^b  \vec h(t)  dt \bigg|\bigg| \leq  
\int_a^b \| \vec h(t) \| dt$$

Note: This is used as Lemma in one of the lecture videos of Theodore Shifrin and he says this follows simply from Cauchy-Schwarz, ie $|\vec f. \vec g| \leq \|\vec f\|\|\vec g\|$. I was not able to fill the gaps though.

Comment: An integral is just a limit of sums, and $\leq$ is preserved after you take the limit. So it sort of immediately follows from the "normal" triangle inequality.

Comment: I can see that intuitively. So I didn't disrupt the lectures. But a formal proof, especially using Cauchy-Schwarz as hinted by the professor, I can't conjure up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Hint:*** call the components of the integral $J_i$:

$$ \mathbf{J} := \int_a^b \mathbf{h}(t)dt, \qquad J_i := \langle \mathbf{e_i}, \mathbf{J} \rangle = \int_a^b h_i(t)dt,$$
with $\mathbf{e_i}$ the $i$th standard basis vector and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ the default inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
 Then we have:

$$ \lVert \mathbf{J} \rVert^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n J_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n J_i \int_a^b h_i(t)dt = \int_a^b \sum_{i=1}^n J_i h_i(t)dt.$$

Apply Cauchy-Schwarz to $\sum_{i=1}^n J_i f_i(t)$ and simplify.

Comment: Is J integrand of the left side or the result of the integral on the left side?

Comment: @meguli Does my edit answer your question?

Comment: I think I completed the proof now, at some point I said $\|J\|^2  = \int_a^b J \cdot \vec h(t) dt \leq \int_a^b | J \cdot \vec h(t) | dt$ and I think I can say that since the integral is equal to a positive quantity?

Comment: Recognising it as an inner product is indeed the correct step; Cauchy-Schwarz then yields $\mathbf{J} \cdot \mathbf{h}(t) \leq \lVert \mathbf{J} \rVert \cdot \lVert \mathbf{h}(t)\rVert$, and $\lVert \mathbf{J} \rVert$ is constant with respect to $t$.

Comment: Yes I completed by noting that J is constant. Though, shouldn't inner product be in absolute value for us to apply Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: @meguli Not really, the absolute value would just make it stronger, since $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} \leq | \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} |$.

Comment: Lastly, can you direct me to a resource that explains why and when we can take the summation into the integral? When do these operations are order independent?

Comment: The integral is linear so any finite sum can be exchanged with it, as can constants.